# ReadValue from INI File

Tags: c#, foreach, ini

I am a "new" beginner in `C#` and on doing my Project i get one problem i can't solve with my knowledge. I try a lot but it dosent work for me so i hope i can get some help.

```
public void ReadValue()
{
  foreach(string cat in this.ini.iniGetCategories())
   {
     textbox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine , this.ini.iniGetCategories()) + Environment.NewLine + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, this.ini.iniReadValue(cat,"Key");
   }
}
```

`this.ini.iniGetCategories()` - reads all Sections from my INI -- works fine

`this.ini.iniReadValue(string Section, string Key)` - reads the Value from the Key from the Section

**The main Problem is, that it gives me all Section - names but it only gives me the last Key + Value from my INI and ignores the other one**

**29.01.2014 - 10.00**
My actually Code what gives me only "1 Section + 1 Value". The other are still missing...

```
StringBuilder strbuild1 = new StringBuilder();


            foreach (string cat in this.ini.IniGetCategories())
            {
                strbuild1.Append(cat + Environment.NewLine);

                foreach (string ccat in this.ini.IniGetCategories())
                {
                    strbuild1.Append(this.ini.IniReadValue(ccat, "Betreff"));
                }
            }

            textBox1.Text = strbuild1.ToString();
```

Comment: @Schrader your inner loop should not iterate over the categories but over the keys. Since this is your project, I suppose you wrote these methods yourself? You'll need e.g. a method `public List<string> ReadKeys(string section)`

Comment: @WimOmbelets Now my inner loop goes over my `this.ini.iniGetKeys` - Method
I add both loops to my `Stringbuilder` but finally get again one Value... 
And i need only the Value from the one Key "Betreff"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `foreach` loop will assign `textbox1.Text` each time, so it's perfectly normal that only the last `cat` in `this.ini.iniGetCategories()` will be used to assign a retrieved value to the `TextBox`.

If I'm correct in assuming, that you'd like to have ALL category names in that `TextBox`, you would first construct a `String` (using either the `+=` operator or, preferably, using the `StringBuilder` class and only AFTER the scope of the `foreach` loop ends would you then assign that string to the `Text` property of your `TextBox`.

An easy and readable way to achieve this, is to use double nested loops.

the general idea is: for each section in the collection of sections, then for each key in the collection of keys for that specific section

Comment: I make a `foreach` for my Sections and one `foreach` for reading the Key and `append` then to a `Stringbuilder`
But now i get only the first Value ...

Comment: @Schrader please expand your question to also show the code you're tried last

Comment: Its working perfect... give both informations(`Section`, `Key`) to two `Stringbuilder` take them to my `textbox` and clear the `Stringbuilder`and repeat this with `foreach`
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As Wim mentioned using the `+=` operator is useful on your case.

```
public void ReadValue()
{
  foreach(string cat in this.ini.iniGetCategories())
   {
     textbox1.Text += string.Join(Environment.NewLine , this.ini.iniGetCategories());
     textbox1.Text += string.Join(Environment.NewLine, this.ini.iniReadValue(cat,"Key");
   }
}
```

Comment: Work, BUT it only gives me again the "Value" of one "Section"
And i need to get for all "Sections" the "Value" of the "Key"

Comment: you'll need to loop over each key in a section for each section: this yells nested loops. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the shameless plug but I would like to introduce IniParser, a library I've created.  MIT license (can be used even in proprietary code)
Written in c# w/out external bindings, so it contains no dependencies in any OS, which makes it Mono compatible.

You can [check out the source in GitHub](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser), and it is [also available as a NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser)

It's [heavily configurable](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/wiki/Configuring-parser-behavior), and [really simple to use](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/wiki/First-Steps).

Hope it can be of help of anyone revisiting this answer.